# Parse a dictionary of dictionaries using jsonmodel

Tags: objective-c, json, dictionary, jsonmodel

I'm using [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) for working with a JSON Api and now got stuck on parsing a Dictionary of Dictionaries.

```
{
  "locations": {
    "one": {
      "displayName": "Name One",
      "description": "Description One"
    },
    "two": {
      "displayName": "Name Two",
      "description": "Description Two"
    }
  }
}
```

In my example, I need the keys "one" and "two" and their content so I thought about something like this

```
@protocol BaseDataModel;

@interface BaseDataModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary<NSString *, LocationModel> *locations;

@end
```

But this won't work because `LocationModel` isn't a Objective-C Type.

Answer (score 1):

You should just create the class LocationModel:

```
@interface LocationModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSString * displayName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString * description;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the @protocol declaration for your `LocationModel` I think

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol LocationModel;
@interface LocationModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *displayName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;

@end
```